Excluded volume in van der Waals' Equation
As per my understanding, excluded volume is defined as the volume excluded to the rest of the gas molecule's centers because of its presence. During bimolecular collisions, there is some overlap in volume, so the excluded volume is not 8 times the molecular volume. However, in all explanations, only the volume excluded by one sphere is considered, not both. Why not consider the sphere around the second molecule (in the below diagram) as well?


Because two excluded volumes will have intersected volume included twice, which will be too much, so you would need actually to subtract it ?

I would think you take the volume of both imaginary spheres, subtract the region of overlap, and divide by two. That doesn't result in 4V.

You misunderstand the diagram. In the collision of two spheres, both of the same radius $r$, the closest the centre of one sphere can get to the centre of another sphere is $2r$. This is equivalent to having one sphere be of radius $2r$ and the other sphere be reduced to a point mass. In this way, we can see that the correct excluded volume is $\frac43\pi(2r)^3N$, with corrections subtracting from this value by 3-body collisions and higher.
